# How to fetch data from api and show when user scroll

Tags: android

I have an API which gives 10 per page result at once

```
{ item1,
  item2,
  item3,
  .
  .
  item10
}
```

I have RecycleView in which I want to display the result.

```
public class RecycleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecycleAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private Entry[] entry;

    // Provide a reference to the views for each data item
    // Complex data items may need more than one view per item, and
    // you provide access to all the views for a data item in a view holder
    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // each data item is just a string in this case
        TextView labelText;
        TextView descText;
        ImageView itemImage;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            labelText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.item_label);
            descText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.item_text);
            itemImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.item_image);
        }

    }

    // Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
    public RecycleAdapter(Entry[] en) {
        entry = en;
    }

    // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public RecycleAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                   int viewType) {
        // create a new view
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.list_items, parent, false);
        // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters

        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(view);
        return vh;
    }

    // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        // - get element from your dataset at this position
        // - replace the contents of the view with that element
        holder.labelText.setText(entry[position].title);
        holder.itemImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.img);
        holder.descText.setText("Random Text to Recycle");

    }

    // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return entry.length;
    }
}
```

Entry object contains the Array if Object containing data (basically String). instead of this I would like to pass and integer array
denoting the page of API and than I want to list all 10 item of that page

It seems to me that **we can get only one item at a time** in bind function or other way is to **insert all item in Entry at beginning** and than fetch them (which I want to avoid).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `addOnScrollListener` behavior of recyclerView to monitor the scroll, and use `layoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()` to know who's the last item.When you know it you can populate the next 10 items you've fetched before and for a better user experience you can use `adapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(int startPosition, int itemCount)` to notify the list from below that postition so that if for example you had 10 items in the recyclerView before the fetch, so after the fetch you'll notify from last item (via layoutManager method above) to *itemCount* added (in your case 10) then the first 10 displayed will still be shown and the next 10 will be added to the bottom of the recycler, and the user will be able to 'continue' scrolling.

Hope it helps, good luck

Answer (score 0):

Lets say your API gives you X items at a time.  When getView is called with position lastFetchedItem-Y  (where Y is a small number used to give some buffer for network delay) you request the next X items.  When you receive them, you update the model backing your adapter and call notifyDataSetChanged.  This will give you a smooth scroll.  Adjust X and Y for network efficiency (slower networks or slower APIs, bigger Y).

Answer (score 0):

Use `Endless Scrolling with AdapterViews and RecyclerView`

This [tutorial](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Endless-Scrolling-with-AdapterViews-and-RecyclerView) will help you do `paging` functionality.